# rellenar argumentos de un objeto o metodo con Scanner

Tags: java, scanner

El codigo que tengo me funciona pero quiero saber si utilizar Scanner dentro los argumentos para inicializar un objeto se considera normal o de mala practica. el código es el siguiente

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Alumno {
    int edad;
    float altura;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Ingrese la edad (numero entero) y la altura (numeros decimales digitados con \",\") del alumno numero 1.");
        Alumno alumno_1 = new Alumno(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextFloat());
        System.o

    }

    //constructor
    public Alumno(int _edad, float _altura) {
        this.edad = _edad;
        this.altura = _altura;
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Debes considerar el hecho de que tus clientes usualmente no van a tener el código java y abrir el programa en la consola, si no que leerás los datos de algún lugar/interfaz. En cambio, si distribuyes el programa como consola... pues es que no tienes otra manera de que ingresen los datos! Todo depende del contexto de tu programa... Si tienes una interfaz gráfica con campos de texto, el usuario ya no va a tener que tocar la consola con lo cual no vas a tener un scanner. De todas maneras, los datos del usuario **deben VALIDARSE SIEMPRE. Jamás** asumas que tu usuario va a hacer las cosas *bien*

Answer (score 0):

Te diria que se podria llegar a considerar "mala practica", pero aun asi, todo depende para que fines sea realizado. Si no tienes que hacer ninguna comprobación con las datos que recibes, o si llega a esa clase con las comprobaciones hechas anteriormente, osea, que sean datos sin posibilidad de error, yo creo que puedes dejarlo asi.

Que pasa? Que es mejor tener el control de los posibles datos que esten introduciendo, en pocos casos llegarás a usar algo así, ya que tendrás que controlar los datos de entrada para despues crear los objetos.